# Serialization of List<T> to single XML Element with nested Elements

Tags: c#, xml

I'm tying to create an XML file from those classes in the following form:

What i'm getting:

```
<photographer name="Meggan Danzy" primary-camera="Pentax K-500">
<lenses>
  <LensDto>
    <lens>Pentax 2.8mm f77</lens>
  </LensDto>
  <LensDto>
    <lens>Pentax 1.2mm f10</lens>
  </LensDto>
  <LensDto>
    <lens>Pentax 2.8mm f135</lens>
  </LensDto>
</lenses>
```

What I want to achieve

```
  <photographer name="Meggan Danzy" primary-camera="Pentax K-500">
<lenses>
    <lens>Pentax 2.8mm f77</lens>
    <lens>Pentax 1.2mm f10</lens>
    <lens>Pentax 2.8mm f135</lens>
</lenses>
```

The code is the following:

```
    [XmlType("photographer")]
public class SameCameraDto
{
    [XmlAttribute("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("primary-camera")]
    public string PrimaryCameraMake { get; set; }

    [XmlArray("lenses")]
    public List<LensDto> Lenses { get; set; }
} 

   public class LensDto
{
    [XmlElement("lens")]
    public string Data { get; set; }
}
```

How can I remove this "LensDto" tag ?

Comment: Change from : [XmlArray("lenses")] to : [XmlElement("lenses")].  XmlArray adds an extra layer of tags.

Comment: This method gives the same result.

Comment: No it doesn't, but you need to change XmlElement("lenses") to XmlElement("lens") and public List<string> Lenses { get; set; } instead of public List<LensDto> Lenses { get; set; } LensDto not needed.

Comment: Thanks! This solution suits my needs.